# Any way to remove the red/green color of report.html output from robot framework api using python script

Tags: api, robotframework

I am using below code to run the suite i have created. it is working fine.

```
suite.run()
# suite.run(critical='Medium')
# Reading from output XML and creating Report and Log files
writer = ResultWriter('output.xml')
writer.write_results(report='report.html', log='log.html')
```

i need to remove the green/red color coming in the report.html output file.
is there any argument in the function call to do that?

Comment: Do you want to remove _all_ uses of green and red, or only the background color?

Comment: Only the background

Answer (score 3):

You could pass parameter `reportbackground`, to `write_results` function.

```
writer = ResultWriter('output.xml')
writer.write_results(report='report.html', log='log.html', reportbackground='#ffffff:#ffffff:#ffffff')
```